# how to avoid XSS while decoding html

Tags: xss, htmlspecialchars, richtext

First of all, the thing that I want to do is to show decoding version of the the value that is came from rich-text editor. I mean that if the value that is came from rich-text editor is coming as bold, I want it to show as **like this**, not  <.b.>like this<./b.> 
I know that we can do it with php function which is called *htmlspecialchars_decode()*. But I want to write it with avoiding XSS. Is it possible to do it? If it is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just replace or the bad tags you do not want to show up, such as  or ect...

Comment: Thats actually not that easy. There are so many tags that can cause xss. Actually most of them, given the right attributes (onmouseover etc).

Comment: This is true, another quick and simple method is to replace the < and > with the equivilant html entities.